# Banach space and Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm trying to understand Hilbert spaces and Banach spaces, and there is specifically one thing that I don't understand.

As of my understanding the Hilbert space have a scalar product that is defined by $$<f,g> = \int f(x)\overline{g(x)} dx$$

My question is, does the Banach space also have some kind of scalar product, and if not - why not?

Thanks!

Comment: The norm should satisfy the  [parallelogram identity](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-parallelogram-identity-for-inner-product-spaces#toc0)

Comment: A Banach space may have no scalar product. You can define a scalar product on a Banach space if and only if its norm satisfies the [Parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces).

Comment: Another comment.  Conjugate space. (I do real scalars for simplicity.)   If $E$ is a Banach space, there is a bilinear form $E \times E^* \to \mathbb R$ with nice properties.  If $E$ is a (real) Hilbert space, then $E$ is canonically isomorphic to $E^*$ and this becomes the inner product $E \times E \to \mathbb R$,